# How I count a specific characters in a String in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I have this in my collection at MongoDB, so I need to count in MED0 only the commas and return 4. 
[image]

When I do this in Firebase, it is something like that:

```
let medRef = db.ref('root/users/id1/MED0');
// change the object in an element of array
   function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
      let returnArr = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          let item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;
        str= item.split(/\d+/).length;//split divide a string in an array of strings, and I use /\d+/ 
      //lenght counts the characters
          returnArr.push(str - 2); //-2 no count []
      });
      return returnArr;
  }; // on() synchronize data and snap is a snapshot of database

medRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshotToArray(snapshot));
});
```

So how I do the same in Mongoose and return the value at my collection in MongoDB?

Comment: Ah, I missed the last line of your question, because it's merged in with the code. Please fix the formatting on your question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Once you define your collection schema/model (`collectionModel`) in your mongoose then you can do that using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) :

```
collectionModel.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            med: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$med', as: 'each', in: {
                        $mergeObjects: ['$$each', {
                            count: {
                                $subtract: [{
                                    $size: {
                                        $split: [{
                                            $arrayElemAt: [{
                                                $let:
                                                {
                                                    vars: { valueArray: { $objectToArray: "$$each" } },
                                                    in: '$$valueArray.v'
                                                }
                                            }, 0]
                                        }, ","]
                                    }
                                }, 1]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D2iKZIDQo5V)

**Note :** As you've complex structure we had to do few additional steps to get it done, check this simple explanation on how it's actually done :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $addFields: { count: { $subtract: [{ $size: { $split: ['$stringValue', ','] } }, 1] } } }])
```

**Steps :**

1. With `$addFields` we're adding a new field called `count` to all documents.
2. Let's start from inner operator `$split` which will split string based on delimiter `,`. So an array of elements separated by `,` **Ex:-** `'a,b,c'` to `[a,b,c]`.
3. Then we're checking size of array using `$size` So it would return `3` for above example (a,b,c as three elements).
4. Finally `$subtract` to subtract length minus `1` to get no.of `,`'s in array.

**Collection Docs :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631707f8bc30a75e40711"),
    "stringValue" : "123,23423,534,56,1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631787f8bc30a75e40800"),
    "stringValue" : ""
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631837f8bc30a75e40991"),
    "stringValue" : "123,1"
}
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631707f8bc30a75e40711"),
    "stringValue" : "123,23423,534,56,1",
    "count" : 4.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631787f8bc30a75e40800"),
    "stringValue" : "",
    "count" : 0.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4631837f8bc30a75e40991"),
    "stringValue" : "123,1",
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

**Ref :** [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)